# TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined Magento 'Add to cart'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

When clicking the 'Add to cart' button on magento *view.phtml* page, I am getting the following error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined
```

I am aware that this is potentially jQuery conflict however I am not sure where the conflict is as I am using jQuery no conflict.

Site URL:

http://www.envirouk.com/index.php/lighting/led/led-flat-panel.html#

Comment: show us how you put jquery in your application?

Comment: I included jQuery onto the website via the page.xml file as follows : <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js</name></action>

Comment: However if I completely remove the jQuery added I still receive the typerror.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a proper way to include jQuery.

You need to add jQuery first then conflict then prototype.

Try with above order.